# Error handling with multiple directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, csv, subprocess

I am trying to remove files from multiple directories.  While:

```
   os.remove("C:/WWWWWWW.csv")
    os.remove("C:/AAAAAAA.CSV”)
```

Tends to work, the code tends to break assuming that one of these directories is not found.

The below also tends to work.  However, if it can’t find `WWWWWWW`, then it tends not remove other directory `.csv` files

```
try:
    os.remove("C:/WWWWWWW.csv")
    os.remove("C:/AAAAAAA.CSV”)
 except OSError:
    pass
```

I have about 18+ files so I am just wondering if there is a cleaner way than having to:

```
try:
    os.remove("C:/WWWWWWW.csv")
 except OSError:
    pass
 try:
    os.remove("C:/WWWWWWW.csv")
 except OSError:
    pass
```

The below tends not to address the issue:

```
try:
    colors = ["C:/d.csv", "C:/a.csv"]
    for color in colors:
        os.remove(color)
except OSError:
    pass
```

Comment: make a list of the files and pass them through a for loop

Comment: @0TTT0 Can you give an example of how that is done?

Comment: Are you trying to delete certain types of file (i.e.  .csv, .txt) etc or all files in directory

Comment: @Gumboy .csv files

Comment: @0TTT0 There are lots of solutions for deleting csv files in a folder but not so many when you have other crucial csv files that you are not wanting deleted in that directory or when you have files in F drive.

Comment: If your csv files follow a naming convention (i.e.  big1.csv, big2.csv) you can use regex and delete those files only

Comment: you may want to move your list and for loop outside of the try, except block..

Comment: @0TTT0 This can only really be done with one folder though.  It tends to become quite complex when using multiple directories as you have to create a block for each directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible solution, also mentioned by @OTTO

```
del_list = ['file1.csv', 'file2.csv', 'file3.csv'];

for fd in del_list:
    try:
        os.remove(os.path.join(my_dir, fd))
    except OSError:
        pass
```

You first need to create a list of file names that you want to delete in any directory `my_dir` you will be cleaning. The loop goes through the list and uses error handling that prevents the program from exiting if a file is not present in that particular directory. You can turn this program into a function and call it for each directory you want to delete files from or add another, outer loop that goes through a list of your target directories.

Comment: Thanks.  Provided this does not delete any files I don't want not deleted, this is a much cleaner method :).

Comment: It does cause problems when I want to use other directories though which would create lengthy code.

Comment: Are the files in other directories also from that one particular file name list? Or there is no naming convention across directories?

Comment: I should have been more specific in my question (I could create a new question).  But here's how the data looks in general: C:\1A.csv
    C:\2A.csv
    C:\3\3A.csv
    C:\4\4A.csv
    C:\5\5A.csv
    C:\6\6A.csv
    C:\7\7A.csv
    C:\8\8A.csv
    C:\9\9A.csv
    C:\10\10A.csv
    C:\11\11A.csv
    C:\12\12A.csv
So there's a lot of different folders.

Comment: I'm not sure if you have to create a different question, follow ups like this seem ok - up to you. Are the directories really called 1,2,3 etc? Is there any rule to how you call your files and directories?

Comment: The directories tend to be called (Number) followed by a word.  I could rename them to numbers if that would help and create a text to remind myself which folder is which.

Comment: @OTTO Thank you :) I was actually waiting for a bit in case you wanted to post it, planned to upvote as well ;)

Comment: If you have a naming convention like number_word and the word is the same in all cases, then it's easy to create a list of directory names that you can then loop through. In each iteration of the loop you would execute the program in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob, os, os.path
mydir = 'set directory here'
# Deletes all csv files in the directory specified, ignoring case
for fil in glob.glob(os.path.join(mydir, "*.[Cc][Ss][Vv]")):
    os.remove(fil)
```

Comment: I tend to get for: mydir = "C:/d.csv", "C:/a.csv" - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Comment: mydir should be equal to the directory not a file or tuple use: `mydir='C:/'`

Comment: Did it delete the all .csv files?

Comment: @Gumboy maybe add some description to your code and clearly indicate that this deletes all the csv files in the directory.

Comment: @atru The thing is I have other csvs in my c directory as well as other files on F drive so assuming it works not really what I am after :/

Comment: I could just bite the bullet and have 70 lines of code for deleting specific files LOL.  I have this elsewhere.  So about 300 lines for what should be about 20

Comment: Then you definitely don't want to use this code. @OTTO suggestion is the way to go.